# Get custom attributes from an c# event

Tags: c#, events, custom-attributes

Is it possible to get the custom attributes from an event?

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Test()]
    public event EventHandler TestEvent;

    public void RunTest()
    {
        //Get attributes from TestEvent
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Event)]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

I tried the following, but both yielded no result:

```
Console.WriteLine("Attr: {0}", Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(TestEvent.GetMethodInfo(), typeof (TestAttribute)) != null);
Console.WriteLine("Attr: {0}", Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(TestEvent.Method, typeof (TestAttribute)) != null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because events are a special kind of delegate, the [.Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.delegate.method) you're referring to there specifies the event handler, not the event itself, and thus not the attributes attached to the event. Instead, you can reference the event via reflection from the Class itself using the [GetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Console.WriteLine("Attr: {0}",
    Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
        typeof(TestClass).GetEvent("TestEvent"),    // This line looks up the reflection of your event
        typeof (TestAttribute))
    != null);
```